# Scheme function definition how to do it

Tags: scheme

Use comp to define the pos-cos function:

```
pos-cos(x) = 
    cos(x)    if cos(x) ≥ 0   else
    −cos(x)   if cos(x) < 0
```

```
(define (comp f g)
  (lambda (x) (f (g x))))

(define (pos-cos x)
  (if (< (comp (cos x) x) 0)
      (* -1 (cos x))
      (cos x)))
```

This is what I have so far. But it gives me an error saying contract violation. I am new to scheme and cannot figure out the error. Can someone please look over my code? Thank you.

Comment: *What* "gives you an error"? Show the exact code you're running please.

Comment: Can you combine `abs` and `cos` somehow?

Comment: This is the exact code I am running. Supposed to use the comp function to calculate the cos of x. If its greater than 0 then regular cosx, less than zero, -cosx

Comment: no you don't. you are not running this exact code, because all you've shown are two definitions, and no function calls. I copy-pasted your two definitions, loaded the file, and it gave me no error messages what-so-ever.  e.g. `(sin 0.5)` is a function call. show us ***that***.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're using function composition in the wrong place. Truth is, you don't need it at all...

```
(define (pos-cos x)
  (if (< (cos x) 0)
      (- (cos x))
      (cos x)))
```

But ok - just to satisfy some arbitrary requirement, we can compose `abs` and `cos` to take the absolute value of the result of the cosine of `x`, that's equivalent to the `if` expression we had before:

```
(define (pos-cos x)
  ((comp abs cos) x))
```

Notice the double parentheses up there at the start of the second line? that's important! remember that when we apply `comp` it returns a new `lambda`, and we have to apply it again to `x` to obtain the expected result.

Comment: @CarterWilson I hope this post was useful for you! If you think so, please don't forget to [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left ;) It's worth reading: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)